Can I combine these two flows into only one?
I'm currently having 2 flows which have the kind of the same job, which is removing all the attachment of a case after it's closed. The first flow is used to delete all the Content Document and Content Document Link, and the 2nd flow is to delete all the file in Attachment obj because my customer is using Salesforce classic. Are there any ways to combine these 2 flows into 1. I have tried several ways but it didn't work properly. Really hope to have some advice from you guys. Thanks.

Updated: I have just figured out the a solution, is there anyway to improve this flow?


Given the size of your flows, can't you just manually add the second flow to your first flow?

I have tried to combine 2 flows by connecting the second flow immediately after the first flow is completed, or another way I have tried is to set the condition of the Decision to have 2 branches, one branch to delete the attachment and one branch to delete the content document. But both cases have the problem that it will need to run 2 times to delete on both sides. The result I want is that if the case is closed, both the content document and the attachment are deleted at the same time.

Please edit your question to include more information.  You say you've tried, but it's unclear why it's not working.  Isn't your first 'get records' getting the contentdocumentlinks, and the second 'get records' is getting attachments?  you should be able to just perform one after the other.

Hi Nick C, I have just have a new update in my question. Can you have a look?

Did you already tried using SubFlows? Whatever logic that can be re-used you can put that in SubFlow, then your Flow can call that SubFlow which effectively combines 2 flows into 1
